# Send data in res.send method fetched from two collections node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two collections `categories` and `subcategories` each category have multiple subcategories. And in `subcategories` collection each document have a `category_id` field. and now i want when i am fetching data for a particular `subcategory` from that with `category_id` fetch category details here is my code i am not getting any response from '`data.category_id`'
Here is my code

```
exports.TopicsBySubcategoryId = (req, res) => {
    Subcategory.findOne({
        _id: req.params.id
    })
    .then(obj => {
        if (obj != null && obj != '') {
            console.log(obj)
            console.log(obj.category_id)
            Category.findOne({
                _id: obj.category_id
                }).then(data => {
                    if (data != null && data != '') {
                        console.log(data)
                        res.send({ response: true, message: 'Data fetched successfully', data:{category : data, subcategory : obj} })
                        return
                    } else {
                        console.log('not found')
                        res.send({ response: false, message: 'Server mmmencountered some error' })
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                    res.send({ 
                        response: false, 
                        message: 'Server mmmencountered some error !!!' 
                    })
                    return
                })
        } else {
            res.send({ response: false, message: "Server mmmencountered some error !!!" })
        }
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
        res.send({ response: false, message: 'Server encountered some error !!!' })
        return
    });
};
```

Here is the output

```
{ _id: 5c398cb7d301362158004fce,
Title: 'dsgds',
Description: 'gdsgsgsg',
Slug: 'sgdsgdsg',
category_id: '5c398ac7d301362158004fcd',
UserId: '5c3796cad3013606e8001f9c',
updated_at: 2019-01-12T06:44:07.000Z,
created_at: 2019-01-12T06:44:07.000Z }
undefined
not found
```

`obj.category_id` gives nothing,

`subcategory`

```
let SubcategorySchema = new Schema({
    Title: {type: String, required: true},
    category_id: {type: String, required: true},
    Description: {type: String, required: true},
    Slug: {type: String, required: true},
});
```

`category`

```
let CategorySchema = new Schema({
    Title: {type: String, required: true},
    Description: {type: String, required: true},
    Slug: {type: String, required: true},
});
```

Comment: add your Schemas category and subcategory

Comment: @THEWOLF added sir

Comment: are you sure the ObjectId you have saved is the correct one ? this - category_id: '5c398ac7d301362158004fcd'

Comment: Did you try `obj.get('category_id')` to get the value?

Comment: it's working now